# Подводные камни перемещения объектов используя атрибуты вместо матрицы трансформации

Tags: javascript, webgl, шейдеры, vertex-shader

Какой вариант практичнее? Перезапись буфера атрибутов или же перемещение с помощью матрицы трансформации?

Третью недель вникаю в WebGL и пытаюсь сделать маленькую 2D игру для развития. Пришла пора добавить персонажам вращение и поэтому сразу решил сделать это с помощью матриц. Я раньше не задумывался, но с помощью матриц можно делать и обычное перемещение объектов.Перемещение у меня сделано на перезаписи буфера атрибутов.

Если вспомнить, в некоторых шутерах, в начале игры все персонажи стоят на одной точке, а потом их немного раскидывает по разным местам. Мне кажется, это про мой случай, игроков, изначально, инициализировали с помощью атрибута в одно место, а потом матрицей распределили по своим местам.

Comment: Непонятно что вы имеете ввиду. Что у вас такое "перезаписи буфера атрибутов" и как она вами используется для перемещений?

Comment: @Kromster в вершинном шейдере это `attribute` чтобы в него записать значение нужно сначала создать буфер, наполнить его, и прикрепить к атрибуту. Для перемещения объекта я постоянно перезаписываю буфер. Так получается анимация движения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Классический и правильный метод - перемещение с помощью матрицы трансформации.

Преобразование атрибутов (положения) руками, это очень неэффективный метод (вы перезаписываете буфер каждый раз). Да, вам может казаться, что проще руками все вершины подвинуть на +X +Y вместо *сложного матричного умножения*, однако вы это делаете на CPU и загружаете новый буфер на GPU каждый раз, в то время как ваш GPU мог бы заниматься полезным делом - рисовать. В то же время, трансформация положения тысяч и даже миллионов вершин на GPU дается практически даром (при современных мощностях видеокарт).

Это также неэффективно с точки зрения ООП. У вас должен быть объект (персонаж) и его положение (на уровне). Это две разных *сущности* и не стоит их сливать в одну "персонаж в положении".

Также, если у вас будет несколько одинаковых персонажей, то вы сможете рисовать их из одного буфера, просто передавая разные матрицы трансформации, вместо того чтобы для каждого заводить по уникальному буферу.

---

Модификация атрибутов (т.е. изменение геометрии самой модели) может иметь смысл для визуализации расчетов с CPU (например, если у вас был бы редактор 3Д моделей или физика).

---

> Если вспомнить, в некоторых шутерах, в начале игры все персонажи стоят на одной точке, а потом их немного раскидывает по разным местам

Это к делу никак не относится, т.к. это просто организация загрузки уровня, когда конструктор создает объекты отдельно от их расстановщика по местам.

Comment: Спасибо большого, такого ответа я и ожидал :) Пойду переделывать.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов надеюсь помог. Если что - обращайтесь!

Comment: > вы сможете рисовать их из одного буфера <
т.е. вызывать drawArrays столько раз сколько персонажей? Хм интересно, надо попробовать.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов примерно так сделана какая-нибудь "They Are Billions", или же, если взглянуть шире, то многие повторяющиеся объекты в играх (деревья, итп)

Comment: Однако, если повторов очень много (сотни), то может быть эффективнее уже передавать буфер в котором сразу 100 копий объекта, и 100 матриц пачкой, и перемножать каждый на свою. Т.о. за один более толстый вызов отрисовки рисуется сразу 100 объектов, а не приходится 100 раз дергать легкий объект с разными матрицами.

Comment: к примеру у меня есть сетка из 200+ ходов, она статичная по положению и только меняет цвет при наведении. Матрица в ней не нужна. Мне кажется эффективнее сформировать сразу все вершины. А не создавать для каждого квадратика отдельную матрицу.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов скорее всего верно. Может зависеть от других факторов впрочем.

Comment: > сразу 100 копий объекта и 100 матриц пачкой < объект (если это не точка) всегда состоит из множество вершин, а если матрицу передавать в буфере атрибута, тогда она будет дублироваться на каждую вершину. Мне кажется это крайне неоптимизировано. Сейчас я касаюсь только WebGL1, возможно в WebGL2 всё намного проще.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов "100 матриц пачкой" не атрибутами, конечно, а могут передаваться либо в текстуре, либо переменными.